# Excel: Create index row from cell contents

Tags: excel, indexing, cell

I have a Number in A15, and I need to use that number to fill row #10 with values so if A15 = 8 for example the contents of row #10 would be...

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
 1                                      
 2                                      
 3                                      
 4                                      
 5                                      
 6                                      
 7                                      
 8                                      
 9                                      
10  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried looking into the Index function, tried looking into macros with split and transpose but to no avail... after fiddling around with some functions I started looking online because I'm not very code savvy and here I after a while of looking around I ended up here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this basic formula in A10,

`=IF(COLUMN()<=$A$15, COLUMN(), "")`

Fill right as necessary to populate the cells in row 10.